# I have DevExpress 9.1 source code, and I want to debug in it, how to do it?

Tags: build, debugging, devexpress

It took me two days to try to build the DevExpress source code to make debugging. But can not do it, anyone know how to debug the DLL which is not?

MQ

Answer (score 0):

- You have to install ALL components from DXperience suite
- Download proper build scripts from http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/ViewKBIssue.aspx?kbid=A609
- Follow all instructions in readme.txt contained in downloaded zip. In particular:

  1. do not move component sources. For some reason they must be compiled in their install location (something like %Program Files%/Devexpress 2009.1/Components/Sources)
  2. copy all build files into that location
  3. edit defines.bat, so that configuration=Debug and vsver=your_version_of_visual_studio
  4. run buildall.bat
- update your references to DevExpress assemblies, because after compilation they are signed with different strong key.

Now you should be able to debug their assemblies.